# Optimization using Quantum Logics

Tags: qiskit, programming, resource-request, optimization

Is it possible to solve the following kind of optimization using Quantum Computing?

```
Minimize
5*x1 - 7*x2

binary
x1
x2
```

If yes, is it possible to have a sample code using `QISKit`?

Comment: Are you sure you want linear polynomial here? Not even quadratic $x1^2$, $x2^2$ or $x1*x2$ terms?

Comment: Well as a beginner, I'm trying to learn to solve simple linear problems. Next, with multiple constraints, then non-linear and so on... Shall I include them in this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qiskit has an optimization module and you can find tutorials that illustrate its functionality [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/optimization/index.html).

To solve the example you posted, e.g., with the Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm (QAOA), you can do the following:

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.optimization import QuadraticProgram
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import MinimumEigenOptimizer

# construct optimization problem
qp = QuadraticProgram()
qp.binary_var('x1')
qp.binary_var('x2')
qp.minimize(linear=[5, -7])

# initialize optimizer
qaoa_mes = QAOA(quantum_instance=Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator'))
qaoa = MinimumEigenOptimizer(qaoa_mes)

# solve problem
result = qaoa.solve(qp)
print(result)
```

which prints:

```
optimal function value: -7.0
optimal value: [0. 1.]
status: SUCCESS
```

Qiskit's optimization module also provides other quantum optimization algorithms for quadratic programs and you can find a more detailed description [here](https://medium.com/qiskit/towards-quantum-advantage-for-optimization-with-qiskit-9a564339ef26).